# AVCaptureDevicePosition.front is not working

Tags: swift, avfoundation, swift3, ios10, avcapturedevice

this is my first question here so if it's not explained well please let me know.

So basically I'm trying to access the front camera with this code:

```
 captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSession?.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080

    let cameraDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withDeviceType: AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera , mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: AVCaptureDevicePosition.front)
   print(cameraDevice!)


    let error: NSError? = nil

    do{
    let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: cameraDevice)

        print(captureSession.canAddInput(input))

        if error == nil && captureSession.canAddInput(input){
            captureSession?.addInput(input)

            stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
            if captureSession.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput){
                captureSession.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
                previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
                previewLayer?.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
                cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
                stillImageOutput?.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecJPEG]

                captureSession?.startRunning()



            }

        }
```

Using that code `print(captureSession.canAddInput(input))` returns `false` but when i change the position to the back camera everything works like a charm. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what device you're using, but on an iPhone 6 / 6plus, that preset resolution is too high for the front camera.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Cameras/Cameras.html

As per the Apple documentation, on those devices the highest still image capture resolution is 1280 x 960.  Try using a lower preset and see if it works on the front camera.

This could explain why it works fine on the back camera, because that DOES support the higher resolution.